# Autoloading in Laravel Tests

Tags: testing, phpunit, laravel, autoload, laravel-3

I'm trying to start writing tests within Laravel.
I think it is good practice to write my own basic TestCase, that runs the test setup (for example migrations).

```php
<?php

class TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // just for example:
        DB::table('categories')->first();
    }

}
```

After that, I want to inherit all my TestCases from the one created above

```php
<?php

class TestExample extends TestCase {
    public function testSomethingIsTrue()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);    
    }
}
```

So now I have three problems:

1. My TestCase throws error, class DB not found. Why the heck is the test not autoloading Laravel Framework Classes?
2. PHPUnit tells me (with a warning) that my TestCase does not contain any tests, but that is my suspected behaviour for this class, how can I avoid this message?
3. My TestExample cannot find the class TestCase.

Can you help me understanding that?! How can I configure a test specific autoloading?

UPDATE:
Answer 1: Because I run the tests in NetBeans IDE, that needs to be configured! Setting up the right phpunit.xml helped

Comment: You tagged Laravel 3, but `Artisan` is a Laravel 4 class, mixing up?

Comment: Okay yes, this definitely could be... :)

Comment: I just tried out with another Laravel class: DB. This class was not found, too. So the question is still: How can I use Laravel classes in my tests?

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4 then? All classes should work in tests, you are missing something apparent. How are you running tests? Do you have a phpunit.xml in the Laravel root?

Comment: I found one problem! And sorry for not mentioning it. I configured my IDE to run the tests. (NetBeans) But it was not right configured... It missed the phpunit.xml. Now when I run the tests, this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As revealed in our discussion, when you run your PHPUnit tests using your IDE (NetBeans, PhpStrom and so), you have to make sure your IDE is correctly configured to catch `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: just one last question though (for verification): to generate a testcase, that runs a basic setup, this should be a abstract class, as it cannot be run by phpunit. and then my tests extend this one, and should call within the setup its parent setup method. then i need a require of the php file containing the class, so that the class is found?! this is the way, i solved it now, but is it the right way? thank

Comment: In Laravel 4 there is a TestCase class already and it is autoloaded, why do you have to require it again?

Comment: I have put the testcase in the autoload on start.php, that works, too. So now I don't have to repeat the require_once on every test file.